# Delete MiKTeX setup files

Tags: miktex

I just installed complete MiKTeX 64 bit. I noticed the setup files lie in my AppData/Local/Temp folder and it's taking up about 1 GB. Does it contain any important files for MiKTeX to run or can I safely delete it?

Comment: Is your installing functioning properly? Did you install it to that folder (hopefully not, but to C:\Program Files\ instead)?

Comment: Yes it is fine. I installed to a separate folder in C:\Program Files, yes.

Comment: Then you should be able to delete it safely. The TeX Distribution Structure (TDS), once installed, includes everything (local and university) in the same folder structure (unless otherwise specified during setup). Note that you may still require an editor in order to "properly" use (La)TeX. See [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](http://goo.gl/3f1mL).

Comment: All right great. Already have editor and everything else set up. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

For ease of distribution, TeX can be downloaded in its entirety as an archived bundle. This archive is stored in a temporary location before being extracted to a location of your choice on your local drive. Once installation is complete, you can safely remove this temporary download.